# How to trottle or set internet speed in android phone?

Tags: android, performance, android-networking, android-internet

I want to set my internet speed for test some app. so that can manage internet speed as per requirement. I am getting 4G speed in my location. so that i am unable to manage that. so why i am looking this. i searched many but not getting my point. so can anyone tell me how can i do. it before i was using I-Ball Gorgeo Tablet. where i was a feather where i can up and down my internet speed. so that way i want to make
app that able to up and down internet speed that also work on Host-pot. that means when i slow done my internet speed that upto 40kbs then my phone and host-pot should work in that speed.

Comment: You can set internet speed in mobile via some 3rd paty apps.

Comment: thank you for your valuable reply.  if i will use 3rd paty app. show why i am leaning Android.